# upgrading lein project from clojure 1.2.1 to 1.3.0-beta1

Tags: clojure, leiningen, swank

I have a leiningen project that uses clojure 1.2.1. I would like to add a dependency to a package that requires clojure 1.3.0-beta1. So I decided to upgrade my project to the newer version.

To be honest I was not sure what that involved but I did the following..

In my project.clj I changed my dependency from 
[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1] to [org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]

I use swank so I changed my swank clojure dependency to [swank-clojure "1.3.2"].

I then ran

lein deps

Lastly I manually edited my /usr/bin/lein file to change the CLOJURE_JAR variable to point to the newer clojure jar.

When I start swank with 'lein swank'. It starts fine and I now get the following warning messages 
like so..

> Warning: *default-javac-options* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, >but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *default-javac-options* or >change the name.

Which I think has to do with clojure 1.3.0.

I then fire up Aquamacs and run slime-connect. The REPL starts fine but when call clojure-version
if get "1.2.1".

; SLIME 20100404
user> (clojure-version)
"1.2.1"

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

I think, that you need to add `:exclusions` list to `swank-clojure` specification, something like:

```
:dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure "1.3.2" 
      :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

although, I just checked my installation, and clojure 1.3 worked out of box. I think, that you just forgot to call `lein clean` before `lein deps`...

Comment: Or perhaps another dependency pulled in the old clojure version as well?

Comment: Thanks, I did not run 'lein clean'. The actual problem is that I was referring to the old clojure 1.2.1 jar in one of my own repositories that I added to the lein classpath. (sheepish grin)

Comment: @Alex, The repository that referred to the old clojure 1.2.1 jar was added to the classpath using :extra-classpath-dirs option in project.clj